# Writing an infinite loop on the command line

Tags: java

Please help me make an infinite loop: after the cases show their answer, the program should instantly ask the user again.

```
package calendartool;

import java.io.Console;

public class CalendarTool {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Console C = System.console();
        int month = Integer.parseInt(C.readLine("Please put a valid month: \n"));
        int year = Integer.parseInt(C.readLine("Please put a valid year: \n"));

            switch (month) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("The month is January!");
                    System.out.println("January has 31 days!");
                    break;

            }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i prefer, but it's a matter of taste...

```
while(true){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop:

```
while(true) {
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: my gawd. im only missing this line "while (true)". thanks for the help bro ^o^

Answer (score 1):

I've always been partial to:

```
for(;;)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

If only because it's quicker to type.

Answer (score 0):

Use do-while loop to ask user that he wants to continue or not.

br is bufferredreader instance variable.

```
 char ch=(char)br.read();
 do
 {
System.out.println("press 1 for month jan");
System.out.println("do you want to continue(Y/N)");

}
while(ch=='Y'||ch=='Y');
```