# Why won't my code work in Java?

Tags: c#, java

Here's my code in C#:

```
        string month;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("put month");

            month = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (month)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("dsad");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("\neheheh!");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nhihihihi");
                    break;

            }
        }while(month!="Quit");
```

Here it is in Java:

```
    Console C = System.console();

    String month;
    int year;

    do {
        month = C.readLine("\nPlease put a valid month: \n");
        switch (month) {
            case "1":

                C.readLine("\nPlease put a valid year: \n");
                System.out.println("\nThe month is January!");
                System.out.println("\nJanuary has 31 days!");
                break; 
        }
    } while (month != "Quit");
```

My problem is that my code in Java won't terminate even if I type the word "Quit".

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882907/writing-an-infinite-loop-on-the-command-line).

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530864/java-why-doesnt-my-string-comparison-work?rq=1

Comment: Because that's not how you compare `String`s. `!=` is checking the *reference value*. You may want to start with the Oracle Java tutorials.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, use [`.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of `==` for comparing strings:

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

If you use `==` (or `!=`), you just test for reference equality, not value equality.

Answer (score 4):

Use `equals` method for equaling.

```
do{
}while (!month.equals("Quit"));
```

Comment: thanks to all you guys. im a total newb in java that's why i tend to make it first on c# to test if the codes work xD

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.equals()` instead of `==` or `!=` for String in Java.
Another point, do not use `!month.equals("Quit")`, it may causes the NullPointerException.

As experienced developers, they always write: `!"Quit".equals(month)`